# visual basic escaping quotes

Tags: vb.net, escaping

I feel dumb for not being able to figure this out, but I can't seem to find a post or google search that seems to get this to make sense to me. I have the following code:

```
Select Case frmRMAT.TblRMATrackDataGridView.Item("courier", 1).Value.ToString
                Case "FedEx"
                    sTrackNum = "<a href=""https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=""" & frmRMAT.TblRMATrackDataGridView.Item("tracking_num", 1).Value
End Select
```

as you can see I have escaped the first part, but I need the actual value to be included. It is currently giving me this value:

```
sTrackNum = "<a href="https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers="689691090971 "
```

So I do not need the " before the actual tracking number. How do I manipulate the quotes so that I obtain a proper html string? Thanks

Comment: What’s your problem? The code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit the quotes you don't want to have.

Use

```
sTrackNum = "<a href=""https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=" & frmRMAT.TblRMATrackDataGridView.Item("tracking_num", 1).Value
```

instead of

```
sTrackNum = "<a href=""https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=""" & frmRMAT.TblRMATrackDataGridView.Item("tracking_num", 1).Value
```

---

You could also use XML literals:

```
sTrackNum = <a href=<%= "https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=" & frmRMAT.TblRMATrackDataGridView.Item("tracking_num", 1).Value %>></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! I had to modify to include the closing </a> and endquote but you put me on the right path. I did try the XML version but it didn't return the value as a hyperlink. I used "test" as a string between the closing > and </a> in your code, and that value was returned however it was not formatted as a hyperlink.